# THREE CSS3DObject documentation?

Tags: css, three.js, dart

I see demos and questions about Three's CSS3DObject **BUT** where are the docs for it? I am really interested since manipulating the 3D properties of css with three.js has too much sense.

**Note:** Even Google Dart has docs for CSS3DObject in their own Three implementation. http://threedart.github.io/three.dart/docs/three/CSS3DObject.html

Answer (score 6):

`CSS3DObject` basically extends `Object3D` and adds a `element` property.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js#L6-L31

Comment: Thanks! I got the same code by inspecting and copying the javascript. But why isn't it in the docs? It was very hard to find.

Comment: `CSS3DRenderer` is part of the examples, not the library, and `CSS3DObject` is part of `CSS3DRenderer`. The examples are not documented.

Comment: @WestLangley That's not totally true, at least not now. `GLTFLoader` is documented, for example.