# Display HTML div in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to show HTML content on the sides of a cube. This entire project is for an Oculus Rift DK2 (using three.js).

Till now, I have worked by taking a screenshot and then loading that image on the TextureLoader. Is it possible to directly show HTML content on the sides of the cube ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas#Drawing_HTML, but with additional complication of WebGL.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve it directly by using three.js ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `THREE.CSS3DObject` to do this. As **MrDoob** himself explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23164350/1697459):

> The `CSS3DObject` basically extends `Object3D` and adds a element property.

There are several CSS3D examples [here on the three.js examles page](http://threejs.org/examples).

One of them is [this YouTube example that loads youtube movies in iFrames on a geometry](http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_youtube) and shows the great possibilities of this object.

[Here a link to a nice tutorial](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/) that will help you achieve your goal.

Comment: Using CSS3D I am unable to use it with VR stereo effect. { var effect = new THREE.StereoEffect(renderer); }

Comment: @Vin2k2 Well, that makes sense since it isn't rendered content. Those examples are using simple html elements with CSS3D.

Comment: @Vin2k2 There will be probably some possibility to do that too, I don't know how though... Maybe you can search a bit on Google? Would be great if you could mention it if you find something.

Comment: @Vin2k2 Maybe [this blog post](http://michael-staub.rhcloud.com/2015/05/11/webvr-mixing-html-and-webgl/) can be of helpful.

Comment: I got an error `THREE.CSS3DObject is not a constructor`, fixed by adding `https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js` script according to https://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/jc6j1wmf